In Python-docx, how to determine the index of the previous paragraph of a table?
I want to extract all the tables in a document, process them, and then paste the new tables and the text of the document into another document in the original order. But in Python-docx, paragraphs and tables have no order-relation at all, what should I do?
from docx import Document

def address_of_table(doc):
    table_num = 0
    for table in doc.tables:
        table_num += 1

    address_list = [int for _ in range(table_num)]

    para_index = 0
    tab_index = 0
    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
        para_index += 1
        #………
        #………
        for table in doc.tables:
            address_list[tab_index] = para_index
            tab_index += 1

    return address_list



You should first open and read the document so you can extract the text and tables.
with open('foobar.docx', 'rb') as f:
    source_stream = StringIO(f.read())
print(source_stream)
document = Document(source_stream)
source_stream.close()
...
target_stream = StringIO()
document.save(target_stream)

If print(source_stream) works, then you have successfully extracted the text and tables.
Next, create a new document and append the text and tables. We did that with document = Document(source_stream).
paragraph = document.add_paragraph('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.')

table = document.add_table(rows=2, cols=2)
cell = table.cell(0, 1)
cell.text = 'parrot, possibly dead'

Read the output you got from the print statement and do a check on it or use string manipulation to figure out what is table.
References
You can refer to these python-docx documentation links here:

How to create new Document
How to open and read documents
Extracting tables
Extracting text


Paragraphs and tables both are body elements of document.
Following code iterates over all body elements and should print all body elements in order they occur in document.
from docx import Document

document = Document('existing-document-file.docx')

body = document._body

for body_element in body.iter_inner_content():
    print(body_element)

